# 16.04 LTS to 18.04.1 LTS upgrade: "Save as" window doesn't show recent locations

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

The Files application shows recent files, but the "Save as" window doesn't show recent locations used. This was a very useful feature in 16.04 LTS.

When I try to save a document in multiple locations, I now have to search for each one through the menu. How do I access the "recent locations" shortcut?

Comment: Did you tried to press `<Alt+R>` in the save dialog?

Comment: @N0rbert thank you for revealing this very secret feature in the Save As dialog. Indeed, this question corresponds with the one pomsky refers to.

Comment: I found another very secret feature, that allows to add "Recent" as a bookmark. That way, it appears also in Save As. Drawback: it appears twice in nautilus and GTK3 File Open dialogs. Added this to the other question.

Answer (score 1):

Someone got confused by [the way "Recent files" was presented](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=751653). To solve the issue, [Gnome Developpers removed the option](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=781819). (I am being deliberately a bit sarcastic here).

So indeed, for now, the feature is gone. You may want to add a comment to [Bug 781819](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=781819) to raise the attention to Gnome developpers that the feature may actually be of value.

As a work around, you can (eventually temporary) create a bookmark. A bookmark provides you with an equally quick, if not quicker, access point in the left pane of the dialog. As that approach actually results in a list that is **more predictible and stable** (since you create and manage it yourself), you may actually starting to like that approach.

Bookmarks can conveniently be created in the Save as dialog, i.e. while you are on the way to save a file. Right-clicking the folder where you want to save to create a bookmark. Right-click a bookmark in the left pane to delete or eventually rename it.